# Python Finding Mersenne primes with Lucas-Lehmer sequence and storing them

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to calculate big primes (for fun) on my computer. So far, I have got to a point where it can calculate the primes. However, I am wondering how I can store them and make it so that when the code restarts it continues where it left off. Here is my code:

```
lucas_lehmer = [4]

def mersenne(n):
    return (2 ** n) - 1

def ll(n):
    global lucas_lehmer
    if len(lucas_lehmer) < n:
        for num in range(n-1):
            lucas_lehmer.append(lucas_lehmer[-1] ** 2 - 2)
    return lucas_lehmer[n-1]

def check_prime(n):
    m = mersenne(n)
    if ll(n - 1) % m == 0:
        return m
    else:
        return -1
```

It calculates primes using the Lucas-Lehmer seqence. The sequence starts with 4 and the next number is the number squared, minus 2. Also, the input to the `check_prime` function must also be a prime number.

Comment: store it in a text file?

Comment: It probably will be better if it's a `.json` file but that may work too.

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: see tutorials on how to right data to files and read them, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp or https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're algorithm is suffiently slow that storing and restarting won't be of much value as it bottoms out quickly.  However, it's still a good exercise.

First, this line in your code isn't optimal:

```
for num in range(n-1):
```

As it can cause you to add *more* items to the `lucas_lehmer` array than you need to answer the immediate question.  It should be more like:

```
while len(lucas_lehmer) < n:
```

or the difference between the length of the array and the number you're testing.

What you need to store, in my understanding of this code, is not the primes but your `lucas_lehmer` array so that you don't have to build it up again upon restart of the code.  That's the approach I take below:

**library lucas_lehmer.py**

```
import pickle

PICKLE_FILE = "lucas_lehmer.pickle"

lucas_lehmer = None

def ll(n):
    global lucas_lehmer

    if lucas_lehmer is None:
        try:
            with open(PICKLE_FILE, 'rb') as file:
                lucas_lehmer = pickle.load(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            lucas_lehmer = [4]

    if len(lucas_lehmer) < n:
        while len(lucas_lehmer) < n:
            lucas_lehmer.append(lucas_lehmer[-1] ** 2 - 2)

        with open(PICKLE_FILE, 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(lucas_lehmer, file)

    return lucas_lehmer[n - 1]

def check_prime(n):
    mersenne = (2 ** n) - 1

    if ll(n - 1) % mersenne == 0:
        return mersenne

    return -1
```

This code will create the lucas_lehmer.pickle file for you if it doesn't exist. I tried this with JSON but it got slower slightly sooner with large integers than did Pickle.  Now, you also need test code that you start, stop and restart:

```
from lucas_lehmer import check_prime

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2

    for divisor in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if number < 0:
        break

    if is_prime(number):
        print(number, check_prime(number))
    else:
        print(number, "not prime!")
```

The key to this is you need to instrument your library to make sure that it's initializing, loading and dumping correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cdlane !